# Call function to generate the value but without plotting the graph

Tags: r, plot

I have a function where it is possible to generate a map and a `coef_val` value, but I would like to know if it is possible to call this same function and get just the generated value, without plotting the graph? One possibility that I know exists is to make a new function, for example, `f2`, without the plotting part, but I wouldn't want to do it this way. Is there another way?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


Test <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-01"),
       Category = c("FDE","ABC"),
       Week= c("Friday","Monday"),
       DR1 = c(14,11),
       DR01 = c(14,12), DR02= c(14,12),DR03= c(19,15),
       DR04 = c(15,14),DR05 = c(15,14),
       DR06 = c(12,14)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median),.groups = 'drop')
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum),.groups = 'drop') %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  if(as.Date(dmda) < min(as.Date(df1$date1))){
    datas <- datas %>% 
      group_by(Category) %>% 
      slice(1:max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup
  }else{
    datas <- datas %>% 
      group_by(Category) %>% 
      slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
        df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup
  }
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,45), ylim= c(0,30),
       xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
  
  model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
  
  new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
  new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
  lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
  coef_val<-coef(model)[2]
  points(0, coef_val, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
  return(coef_val)
}

f1(Test, "2021-07-01", "ABC")
b2 
12.5
```

[image: img]

Comment: Yep - `f <- function(x, plot=TRUE) {if(plot) plot(x); return(x)}`

Comment: I don't understand where to insert this. And wouldn't you have to have the part of the day and category chosen? for example: `f1(Test, "2021-07-01", "ABC")`

Comment: It's just an example to show that you can return a value and chose whether you want the graph or not. Wrap all your `plot` `points` etc bits inside an `if(plot) {...}` and then add a `plot=` argument to your function to choose whether it happens or not.

Comment: Specifically, you need to wrap conditionals around `plot`, `lines`, and `points`.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Could you leave it in the form of an answer, so I can test it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an argument that allows users to choose whether to plot or not, `FALSE` by default below. Then just wrap the call to `plot()` with an if statement that executes if the argument is `TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


Test <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-01"),
       Category = c("FDE","ABC"),
       Week= c("Friday","Monday"),
       DR1 = c(14,11),
       DR01 = c(14,12), DR02= c(14,12),DR03= c(19,15),
       DR04 = c(15,14),DR05 = c(15,14),
       DR06 = c(12,14)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse, plot = FALSE) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median),.groups = 'drop')
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum),.groups = 'drop') %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  if(as.Date(dmda) < min(as.Date(df1$date1))){
    datas <- datas %>% 
      group_by(Category) %>% 
      slice(1:max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup
  }else{
    datas <- datas %>% 
      group_by(Category) %>% 
      slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
        df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup
  }
  
  model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
  coef_val<-coef(model)[2]

  if(plot){
    new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
    new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
    
    plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,45), ylim= c(0,30),
           xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
    lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
    points(0, coef_val, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
  }

  return(coef_val)
}
```

Demonstrating it in use:

```
f1(Test, "2021-07-01", "ABC")
f1(Test, "2021-07-01", "ABC", plot = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please let me know if this answered your question :) if so, please click the checkmark next to it in order to accept it. otherwise I am happy to clarify/edit if needed.

Comment: Sorry for delay and thanks for reply @BHudson. When I do `f1(Test, "2021-07-01", "ABC")`, it appears the following error: `Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :   plot.new has not been called yet `

Comment: @JVieira ; thats because the following plot commands  `lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)` and `points(0, coef_val, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)` also need to be wrapped in the `if(plot)` statement. (so need to move the if/plot statement after the nls call

Comment: Thanks for reply @user20650. I did it as you said, it generated the figure and also the coefficient. But that's not what I wanted, just the coefficient value. If you can, you could put your answer.

Comment: @JVieira; I updated BHudson's answer so you shouldn't get the error you mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014020/call-function-to-generate-the-value-but-without-plotting-the-graph/70048090?noredirect=1#comment123911177_70048090) . (hope that's okay BHudson -- I just moved things about a wee bit to avoid the plot errors)

Comment: Thanks for answering. It worked, if I do `f1(Test, "2021-07-01", "ABC")`, only the coefficient value appears. But if I use this: `f1(Test, "2021-07-01", "ABC", plot = TRUE)`, the graph didn't generate, only the value appears, but it would have to appear the graph, right?

Comment: Now, it works! Thanks @user20650 and  @BHudson! =)

Comment: @user20650, do you know why in this question I can't generate the plot?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124977/error-in-plot-generation-in-function-in-r It is very similiar to this question

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect the plot to a `NULL` file. Relevant section from `help(pdf)`:

> file: a character string giving the file path. [...]  If it is ‘NULL’, then no external file is created (effectively, no drawing occurs) [...]

So, in order to not produce any plot:

```r
pdf(NULL)
f1(Test, "2021-07-01", "ABC")
dev.off()
```